# convert video by ffmpeg

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

I have problem with converting video.
I have a line in my bash script:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vcodec mjpeg -r 25 out.avi
```

and I recieve an error when I try to run it

```
'NULL @ 0x1cbeb60] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'out.avi
: Invalid argument
```

any idea why this is error is coming up?

Comment: unfortunately it didn't help

Comment: full command line and uncut console output example please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to specify  an output format `-f` to `ffmpeg`:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vcodec mjpeg -f avi -r 25 out.avi
```

`-f avi` denotes output to `avi` format.

Comment: `-f` is generally not needed for normal cli usage because `ffmpeg` can infer the correct format based on the output extension, but it can be useful in scripting where the output may not be explicitly defined.